# Best Way To Go About Caching Millions of Web Pages

Tags: caching, memcached, varnish

I'm trying to come up with a somewhat simple solution to do a two week cache on millions of pages of content. The site in question is hitting MYSQL every time a page is hit some of the pages with more complex queries are taking 2-3 seconds load, My end goal is to get load times to under a second. I was thinking about using Memcached, but I would like to avoid this approach if possible. I basically would prefer a solution that crawls all the pages in question and automatically creates a fresh cache every two weeks. I'm open to all approaches including using a service.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Memcached or [Redis](https://redis.io/) are perfectly viable solutions to store "projected formats of data" that would require lots of `JOIN`s, `GROUP BY`s, or `ORDER BY`s in MySQL.

However, even when accessing caches like Memcached or Redis, the code still has to be accessed. At high scale, for large amounts of data, the PHP runtime and your webserver can become a bottleneck.

### Varnish to the rescue

You did mention the term *pages*, which implies you're actually trying to cache full pages instead of just data sets. In that case I would advise you to have a look at [Varnish](https://varnish-cache.org/).

Varnish is a reverse caching proxy that is purposely built to caches pages at enormous scale. You can use a crawler to warm up the cache and you can leverage `Cache-Control` headers to control the *Time To Live* of objects in the cache.

Here's an example that sets the `TTL` for an HTTP response to *2 weeks*:

`Cache-Control: public, s-maxage=1209600`

You can also set the `TTL` much higher, and then invalidate specific objects in the cache by [purging](https://varnish-cache.org/docs/6.0/users-guide/purging.html#http-purging) them.

### Caching millions of objects

Varnish is perfectly able to cache millions of objects, maybe even billions. The feasibility primarily depends on the size of your HTTP responses, and the amount of memory your system has.

By default Varnish stores its objects in memory. A configurable parameter in Varnish is the amount of memory that is allocated. You can easily allocate 80% of your system's memory to the Varnish process. The overhead of storing an object in cache is just *1 KB* per object.

If your cached objects are just plain text, there should be no issue. If it's binary data (e.g.: images), then you can run out of memory quite quickly.

Running out of memory is not disastrous: an *LRU mechanism* will ensure that when the cache is full, the *Least Recently Used* objects are removed to clear space.

### Conclusion

[Varnish](https://varnish-cache.org/) has become the *de facto* standard for page caching. The [user guide on the website](https://varnish-cache.org/docs/6.0/users-guide/index.html) is a great resource to quickly learn how to setup and configure Varnish.

Comment: Thanks! awesome answer. Yup I'm looking to do a full page cache. Lets say the pages that will be cached are on average 250kb does varnish compress the response if so by how much?

Comment: If your backend servers perform *gzip* content compression, Varnish will store the compressed version of the HTTP response.

If the backend servers send *plain text* HTTP, Varnish can be configured to still store it in Gzip format.

You can also horizontally scale Varnish with and use a *hashing algorithm* to evenly distribute the content across multiple servers.  The loadbalancing itself can be done in Varnish too, using so-called hash directors. 

This results in a top-level cache with hot data and a storage layer where all the data is stored.

Comment: Thanks I appreciate it you did an incredible job at explaining everything. Varnish it is!